# How to kill an unmanaged message box call from a service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a service that makes a call to an unmanaged dll.  On a certain code path, it will open a message box.  Since it's a service, there's no actual window that shows up, but the thread is still blocked.

How do I kill that message box automatically?

Comment: interesting issue, if you plan to consume the dll from a service with no UI there should be no MsgBox ever shown, I actually have a similar problem, we use a third party library that instead of throwing an exception and let me catch it, shows a message box and no exception is thrown. Optimal solution would be to contact the author of the dll and ask to remove the messagebox call or provide an overload that does not show it.

Comment: The optimal solution would be to just have the source code and fix it myself :).  Unfortunately, the options are to either kill it or patch the dll.

Comment: Does this help? http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Dear-Sybase-MessageBoxes-Don%E2%80%99t-Belong-In-Drivers.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the message box is displayed, but not on the interactive window stations and thus isn't visible to any logged on user. You have a few options:

- You can make the service *interactive*. This will allow it to show a message box to the user currently logged on. MSDN has some information about [interactive services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- You can hook the MessageBox export and redirect it to your own code. This can be done using low level Windows API functions.

Comment: By currently logged on user, do you mean a literal person looking at a desktop, or the service account under which it's running?  Also: can you point me in the right direction for hooking MessageBox?

Comment: Windows has the concept of _window stations_ and services normally run in a non-interactive window station without any user to respond to say message boxes. However, you can force a service to interact with the window station of the user currently logged on. You will have to study the documentation to learn the exact details. I did actually hook `MessageBoxA` many years ago, but I have forgot the details. I believe it was Matt Pietrek that provided me with the necessary information in his MSDN column.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask for help with that in another question :)

Comment: It seems that searching for windows API hooking will lead you to shady web sites about hacking etc. However, when I did the `MessageBoxA` hook it was quite straightforward albeit a bit obscure. If I remember correctly I had to redirect a pointer perhaps in the PE header export table of USER32.DLL loaded into my process. Or was it in the import table of the "bad" DLL?